# Date Query in Django

Tags: django

I would like to retrieve all objects form **A**

```
class A(models.Model):
    date_sent = models.DateTimeField()
```

for which **date_sent** is older than 1 day.

I tried:

```
  A(Q((date_sent - datetime.now()).days > 1))
```

but python tells me that **date_sent** is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

result = A.objects.filter(date_sent__lt=datetime.date.today() - timedelta(days=1))
```

Comment: I guess we want to replace "get" with "filter" in case there are multiple objects to be returned. But thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: @user695652 You're right, my mistake. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is the name of your class, I think you have to call `A.objects.get` first:

```
A.objects.get(
   Q((date_sent - datetime.now()).days > 1)
)
```

["Making queries" from the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: That still won't work, for the same reason (`date_sent` not defined).